# Displaying backend response as a message to react redux frontend component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, react-redux

I want to show error messages like `Incorrect password` as an alert or toast when the user enters the wrong password. Right now, I'm only seeing those messages in the network response tab and wondering how to display a response on the frontend.

Here's login controller function:

```js
 loginUser: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      console.log("inside login controller")
      const { email, password } = req.body
      if (!email || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email and password are must" })
      }
      if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid email" })
      }
      const user = await User.findOne({ email })
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: "This email does not exist" })
      }
      if (!user.confirmPassword(password)) {
        // console.log("Password in login controller", password)
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Incorrect password" })
      }

      res.status(200).json({ user })
    } catch (error) {
      return next(error)
    }
  }
```

And the login component looks like:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import validator from "validator"
import { loginUser } from "../actions/userActions"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { toastError } from "../../utils/toastify"

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    }
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const { email, password } = this.state

    const loginData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
    }

    if (!email || !password) {
      return toastError("Email and password are must.")
    }

    if (password.length < 6) {
      return toastError("Password must contain 6 characters.")
    }

    if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
      return toastError("Invalid email.")
    }

    this.props.dispatch(
      loginUser(loginData, () => this.props.history.push("/"))
    )
  }

  render() {
    const isAuthInProgress = this.props.auth.isAuthInProgress
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="field">
          <p className="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
            <input
              className="input"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="email"
              value={this.state.email}
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email"
            />
            <span className="icon is-small is-left">
              <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <p className="control has-icons-left">
            <input
              className="input"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />
            <span className="icon is-small is-left">
              <i className="fas fa-lock"></i>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <p className="control">
            {isAuthInProgress ? (
              <button className="button is-success is-loading">Login</button>
            ) : (
              <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="button is-success">
                Login
              </button>
            )}
          </p>
        </div>
        <Link to="/forgot-password">
          <p className="has-text-danger">Forgot password?</p>
        </Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginForm)
```

**login action**

```js
export const loginUser = (loginData, redirect) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: "AUTH_STARTS" })
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/users/login`, loginData)
      console.log(res.data)
      dispatch({
        type: "AUTH_SUCCESS",
        data: { user: res.data.user }
      })
      localStorage.setItem("authToken", res.data.token)
      redirect()
      toastSuccess("You are now logged in!")
    } catch (err) {
      console.log
      dispatch({
        type: "AUTH_ERROR",
        data: { err },
      })
    }
  }
}
```

**auth reducer**

```js
const auth = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "AUTH_STARTS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthInProgress: true,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        authError: null,
      }

    case "AUTH_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthInProgress: false,
        authError: null,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        isIdentifyingToken: false,
        user: action.data.user,
      }

    case "AUTH_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthInProgress: false,
        authError: action.data.error,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: {},
      }
```

Also, is there a need for similar checks like I have done both in controller and the component like `if (!email || !password)` and `if (!validator.isEmail(email))`. Or should it be only in the backend?

Comment: maybe take a look at a library which manages side effects (like `redux-saga`).

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a separate state in the reducer in place `authError` which holds the API error response, you can leverage it by using a callback function on your `loginUser` dispatch.

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
  /* your-validation-code */
  this.props.dispatch(loginUser(loginData, this.checkForLoginError()));
};

checkForLoginError = () => {
  const authenticationError = this.props.auth.authError;
  if (authenticationError === null) {
    this.props.history.push("/");
  } else {
    return toastError(authenticationError);
  }
};
```

Comment: Is in't stored inside the `authError`  state in the reducer ? `case "AUTH_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthInProgress: false,
        authError: action.data.error,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: {},
      } `

Comment: yeah, it's in `this.props.auth.authError.response.data.message` . I can clearly see in the devtools. But when I consoled this below render, my app crashed and got, `Cannot read property 'response' of null`

Comment: try logging it like this in the `render()`. `if(this.props.auth.authError !== null) { console.log(this.props.auth.authError.response.data.message) }`

Comment: Oh yeah, now it's showing. Btw i always get this annoying error whenever I try to render an array or some other property. And I always use like `this.state && this.state.array`. But i think that's not right. Is there a better way to handle undefined or null state? I mean what is the standard that people use?

Comment: `this.state && this.state.array` is called short-circuiting, it get's the job done without much verbose. One thing you can do is to assign the state to a variable in the render method. Like this `const {array} = this.state` , then you can use `array && <your-code-to-render>`. Also you can use Higher Order Functions which is more clean. Here is a good [article](https://blog.logrocket.com/conditional-rendering-in-react-c6b0e5af381e/) . Btw, did my answer work for you?

Comment: I'm not able to show the message on the first click, like when click on the submit button on the first time, nothing happens, and on the second click, the message shows up.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FY4wvnxHCH/
https://imgur.com/aDdd4Di

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212311/discussion-between-ajin-kabeer-and-hellraiser999).